# Understanding the parts of a kotlin function

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this kotlin function I am using to access data after making a http request using the `fuel` library in android, from a tutorial I am following but certain parts of this function are strange to me as I am learning kotlin:

```
fun search(term: String, skip: Int, take: Int, responseHandler: (result: WikiResult) -> Unit?) {
        Urls.getSearchUrl(term, skip, take).httpGet()
            .responseObject(WikipediaDataDeserializer()) { _, response, result ->
                if (response.statusCode != 200) {
                    throw Exception("Unable to get articles")
                }
                val(data, _) = result
                responseHandler.invoke(data as @ParameterName(name = "result") WikiResult)
            }
    }
```

These I understand so far:

- `responseHandler: (result: WikiResult) -> Unit?`: anonymous function that returns nothing

but I can't understand most of this part:

```
.responseObject(WikipediaDataDeserializer()) { _, response, result ->
                if (response.statusCode != 200) {
                    throw Exception("Unable to get articles")
                } #<-- this I know throws an exception if the response isn't a 200
                val(data, _) = result
                responseHandler.invoke(data as @ParameterName(name = "result") WikiResult)
            }
```

Comment: Might help: [Higher-Order Functions and Lambdas](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html) and [Destructuring Declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`responseHandler: (result: WikiResult) -> Unit?` is a callback (lambda) function.

It says that it will take in a `result: WikiResult` and give this to whatever is calling it.

```
.responseObject(WikipediaDataDeserializer()) { _, response, result ->
                if (response.statusCode != 200) {
                    throw Exception("Unable to get articles")
                } #<-- this I know throws an exception if the response isn't a 200
                val(data, _) = result
                responseHandler.invoke(data as @ParameterName(name = "result") WikiResult)
            }
```

here, where you are calling `responseObject(WikipediaDataDeserializer())`, you are specifying how to handle another lambda function.

`{ _, response, result ->` is simply saying that you are getting 3 values, the first one you don't care for, you're not using it, so you can rename it to `_`, then your `response` object and your `result` object you will be using, so they have been given those names accordingly.

**Edit**

you have to look at it like 2 different methods :

when you call `search`, you'll do this :

```
search("term", 0, 0) { 
 //this is your responseHandler: (result: WikiResult) -> Unit?)
 // in here, you'll get a result: WikiResult
}
```

similarly, when you call this :

```
    Urls.getSearchUrl(term, skip, take).httpGet()
                .responseObject(WikipediaDataDeserializer()) { _, response, result -> ...
```

this entire chain has a callback you get back, and it gives you 3 values, as explained in my answer above.

`val(data, _) = result` is known as `Destructuring Declarations` https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html

but yes, you're correct in your understanding, we are using the response of this callback, destructing it and then triggering the callback with this data

Comment: Let me see if I understand you, so at the end the WikiResult will be passed to the `WikipediaDataDeserializer()` to change that into json format?

Comment: Here `WikiResult` being `data` after the cast!

Comment: actually, you're correct as well, `responseHandler.invoke` is triggering the callback

Comment: Yes, it does kotlin is so fluid in it's syntax almost feels like javascript!

Comment: going to move this to a chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197082/discussion-between-a-local-nobody-and-george-udosen).